# Styling disabled <select> elements

Tags: html, css

Is there a trick to giving disabled (read-only) `select` elements a css style?
I tried

```
 select[disabled] {color:#F00 !important}
```

(or variants using a class, `!important` etc) but that doesn't work in Chrome and IE. It does work in Firefox, but I'm looking for a universal solution.

Comment: As far as I know styling select options or elements is always a tricky prospect I have found that trying to do so does not play well with crossbrowser support. They like to follow their own styling and not let the programmer change those settings

Comment: This looks like the same question as:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829841/styling-disabled-select-dropdown-boxes-in-html

Comment: @tahdhaze09 both of those questions linked to are a year or older things have changed so there is an ability for this question to have a different answer. When raising the POSSIBLE DUPLICATE flag make sure that the linked answer is well explained and recent enough to be applicable.

Comment: No, sorry, I don't see differences between then and now. The modern day browsers act just the same. If I had searched better, I would never have asked this question. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Try input[disabled="disabled"]... it might be buggy http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/attributeselector

You could also just add a class to the disabled selector

Comment: His question doesn't have to do with the selector.  He was confused because browsers restrict styling of disabled elements.