# customize the disabled="disabled" style in IE

Tags: html

I want to customize the disabled="disabled" select style (dropdown) in internet explorer. wish to look like the second image, but in IE it is showing like first image.[1st image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DxM4.jpg)

[2nd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRdPP.jpg)

Comment: Want 2 change the font color and the dropdown button will be look disabled.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling disabled <select> (dropdown boxes) in HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829841/styling-disabled-select-dropdown-boxes-in-html)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the CSS `disabled` selector for that and you can declare a custom stlye for disabled selects something like that.

```
select:disabled {
    background: #dddddd;
    color:red;
}
```