# jQuery - disable select options

Tags: jquery, css

I need some help with jquery condition. I've been searching and testing for hours, any help would be great !!!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($(".select_red option:selected").attr('disabled', 'disabled').hasClass("red")) {
    $(".select_red").addClass("redtext");
  }
})

$(document).on("change", ".select_red", function() {
  if ($(this).find("option:selected").hasClass("red")) {
    $(this).addClass("redtext");
  } else {
    $(this).removeClass("redtext");
  }
})
```

```css
.redtext,
.select_red .red {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="cars">Choose a option:</label>
<select class="select_red" disabled>
  <option>--Select--</option>
  <option class="red">one</option>
  <option>two</option>
  <option class="red" selected>three</option>
  <option>four</option>
</select>
```

I'm a beginner in jquery, and I don't know is this code is written correctly. I have added few things 
The problem is:
Based on condition the enabled select field will be disabled after selecting the option which has class "red". But after the select field is disabled the color is not changing to red. Thanks for reading

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829841/styling-disabled-select-dropdown-boxes-in-html

Comment: You only need to call document ready once, then your jQuery will run after the html loads. Are you trying to make a multiselect control?

Comment: no multiselect. so this below line works ?
 if($(".select_red option:selected").attr('disabled','disabled').hasClass("red"))

Answer (score 0):

You must use your full Jquery code inside document ready function

```
$(function(){
   if($(".select_red option:selected").attr('disabled','disabled').hasClass("red")){
    $(".select_red").addClass("redtext");
      }
      $(document).on("change", ".select_red", function() {
      if($(this).find("option:selected").hasClass("red")){
       $(this).addClass("redtext");
        }else {
        $(this).removeClass("redtext");
       }
       })
})
```

Comment: the above code is applicable to all the select fields in the app ,the color red is applicable to the select disabled fields for which the color red is not required